# Stage environment for Serverless Framework integration testing

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

Serverless Framework has its own integration testing of endpoints, as defined [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/testing/). The documentation does not mention any staging or parameters that can be used for complex authentication or other setup work that may need to be done to verify an endpoint is correctly setup.

Is it possible to use Serverless Framework's integration testing tool with staged information? If so, how? If not, what is the intended purpose of this integration testing framework - simply to verify that an endpoint returns unauthorized errors?

Answer (score 0):

Our implementation on our every lambda functions with http integrations we name our lambda functions like this

```
functions:
  SignedUrlApi:
   handler: src/handlers/api/signedurl/signedurl.handler
   name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-signedurl-api
   events:
    - http:
       path: leads
       method: post
       authorizer:
         type: CUSTOM
         authorizerId:
           Ref: GlobalAuthorizer
       cors: true
```

By using this naming convention we we're able to integration test every environments that we have.